# Missing attributs in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

When I use: s doctrine: schema: update – force to create my table in my database I only get the id attribut none of the others

S doctrine: database: create
s doctrine: generate: form ClubBundle: Club
I haven't touched the entity Club.php file
I've used s doctrine: schema: update – force to create my table
even though the table has multuple variables the only attibut I get in the table is only id!

```
<?php

    namespace ClubBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

      /**
      * Club
      *
      * @ORM\Table(name="club")
      * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ClubBundle\Repository\ClubRepository")
       */
      class Club
     {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="domaine", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $domaine;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return Club
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Club
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set adresse
     *
     * @param string $adresse
     *
     * @return Club
     */
    public function setAdresse($adresse)
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get adresse
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdresse()
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    /**
     * Set domaine
     *
     * @param string $domaine
     *
     * @return Club
     */
    public function setDomaine($domaine)
    {
        $this->domaine = $domaine;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get domaine
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDomaine()
    {
        return $this->domaine;
    }
}
```

Comment: odd. probably should clear and re-warmup the cache

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

and this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --complete --force
```

or

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and if you are using symfony 4 try this

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

then this

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```